# Dropdown for Shipping carrier to show static address

Tags: shipping, onepage-checkout, checkout-page, carrier

I have created a custom shipping carrier in the checkout page like this.
[image]

I have to get a dropdown when I click the Pickup Shipping radio button.
[image]

On clicking the other shipping method, the dropdown should hide.